# rxjava 2: how to dispose a resource after downstream completes processing

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a (`Flowable`) stream of items to be processed in parallel using a single common resource, and the resource must be disposed afterwards. I tried to use `Single.using()` operator, but it disposes the resource before even the first item in the stream is processed.

Sample program (in Kotlin):

```kotlin
package my.test.rx_task_queue

import io.reactivex.Flowable
import io.reactivex.Single
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

object TestCommonResource {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestCommonResource::class.java)
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val queue = Flowable.fromIterable(1..5)
        val resIdx = AtomicInteger(0)
        val resource = Single.using({
            val res = "resource-${resIdx.incrementAndGet()}"
            logger.info("Init resource $res")
            res
        }, { res ->
            Single.just(res)
        }, { res ->
            logger.info("Dispose resource $res")
        }, false)

        val result = resource.flatMap { res ->
            queue.flatMapSingle({ item ->
                Single.fromCallable {
                    logger.info("Process $item with $res")
                    "$item @ $res"
                }
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }, false, 2)
                    .toList()
        }
                .blockingGet()
        logger.info("Result: $result")
    }
}
```

Sample log output:

```
14:30:27.721 [main] INFO my.test.rx_task_queue.TestCommonResource - Init resource resource-1
14:30:27.744 [main] INFO my.test.rx_task_queue.TestCommonResource - Dispose resource resource-1
14:30:27.747 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1] INFO my.test.rx_task_queue.TestCommonResource - Process 1 with resource-1
14:30:27.747 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-2] INFO my.test.rx_task_queue.TestCommonResource - Process 2 with resource-1
14:30:27.748 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-3] INFO my.test.rx_task_queue.TestCommonResource - Process 3 with resource-1
14:30:27.749 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-4] INFO my.test.rx_task_queue.TestCommonResource - Process 4 with resource-1
14:30:27.749 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1] INFO my.test.rx_task_queue.TestCommonResource - Process 5 with resource-1
14:30:27.750 [main] INFO my.test.rx_task_queue.TestCommonResource - Result: [1 @ resource-1, 2 @ resource-1, 3 @ resource-1, 4 @ resource-1, 5 @ resource-1]
```

Using `Flowable.parallel()` instead of `flatMap()` leads to the same result.

Comment: I need to dispose the resource after all operations on all flowable elements are finished. As you can see from the sample log output, the resource is disposed even before the first element is processed by flatMap.

Comment: Because I need this resource to process each element in the stream. I have, say, numbers 1,2,3,4,5 in the stream, the resource is a network connection, and I need to send each number from 1 to 5 over that connection, on I/O scheduler. But the connection is closed even before I can send the first number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disposing happens with the disposal of the source, so if you want to dispose after everything is done, you just need have `singleFunction` return the whole stream:

```
object TestCommonResource {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestCommonResource::class.java)
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val queue = Flowable.fromIterable(1..5)
        val resIdx = AtomicInteger(0)
        val result = Single.using({
            val res = "resource-${resIdx.incrementAndGet()}"
            logger.info("Init resource $res")
            res
        }, { res ->
            queue.flatMapSingle({ item ->
                Single.fromCallable {
                    logger.info("Process $item with $res")
                    "$item @ $res"
                }
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }, false, 2)
                    .toList()
        }, { res ->
            logger.info("Dispose resource $res")
        }, false)
                .blockingGet()
        logger.info("Result: $result")
    }
}
```

Comment: The composability of this solution is doubtful, but it does exactly what I need! Thank you for the answer!